# Order multiple related records dates into one record sequential

Tags: ms-access

I have a main table called tbl_event that has multiple fields. AMong these fields are: id(unique), protocolID, SubjectID and imgDate1.

Now any one patient can have multiple records in this table with no limits as to how many records allowed. I want to take these dates and make them into one record sequentially.

For example if protocolID: 0388813 subjectID: 0001 had 4 records in this tabel and the imgDate1's of those records where 1/1/2011, 6/30/1995, 3/11/2012, 1/1/2000

I would like to return that as

Protocol ID: 0388813 subjectID: 0001 DATE1: 6/30/1995 Date2: 1/1/2000 Date3: 1/1/2011 Date4: 03/11/2012

Thoughts on how to do this in Access?

Comment: There is one potential obstacle to your achieving a solution: You say that there are "no limits as to how many records allowed [per patient]", but Access tables and queries are limited to 255 columns so if if any [protocolID]+[subjectID] has more than 253 records in [tbl_event] then Access will not be able to produce the output you desire.

Comment: Thanks. Well there is no theoretically limit but there is a practical limit of 30 or so. So that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Okay, good. One other point of clarification: Your sample data shows the dates out of chronological order (presumably listed in order by ID) and the desired result shows [Date1], [Date2]... in chronological order. Producing [Date1], [Date2]... in [ID] order is a much simpler case than producing them in chronological order. Is that an absolute requirement?

Comment: Thanks order doesn't matter, but would be nice if we could do it chronologically.  Also each record is linked by two things protocolID and subjectID

Comment: So I was able to make the a table using VBA using a count query to get a max value of records per subject and created a table using a while loop and string concatenation with a counter, now I could delete the table with the VBA and recreate when I need to. Now I just have to figure out how to populate this table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sample data in a table called [tbl_event]

```
ID  protocolID  SubjectID  imgDate1  
--  ----------  ---------  ----------
 1  0388813     0001       2011-01-01
 2  0388813     0001       1995-06-30
 3  0388813     0001       2012-03-11
 4  0388813     0001       2000-01-01
 5  0388813     0002       2013-05-06
 6  0388814     0001       2013-04-14
```

Since we're lucky enough to have an [ID] field we can use the "self-join" trick to produce a ranked list by [protocolID]+[SubjectID]:

```
SELECT ID, protocolID, SubjectID, imgDate1, COUNT(*) AS Rank
FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.* 
        FROM 
            tbl_event t1 
            INNER JOIN 
            tbl_event t2 
                ON t2.protocolID=t1.protocolID 
                    AND t2.SubjectID=t1.SubjectID 
                    AND t2.ID<=t1.ID
    )
GROUP BY ID, protocolID, SubjectID, imgDate1
```

...producing...

```
ID  protocolID  SubjectID  imgDate1    Rank
--  ----------  ---------  ----------  ----
 1  0388813     0001       2011-01-01     1
 2  0388813     0001       1995-06-30     2
 3  0388813     0001       2012-03-11     3
 4  0388813     0001       2000-01-01     4
 5  0388813     0002       2013-05-06     1
 6  0388814     0001       2013-04-14     1
```

In this case we can modify that slightly to give us our (eventual) column names:

```
SELECT ID, protocolID, SubjectID, imgDate1, "Date" & Format(COUNT(*), "00") AS ColName
FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.* 
        FROM 
            tbl_event t1 
            INNER JOIN 
            tbl_event t2 
                ON t2.protocolID=t1.protocolID 
                    AND t2.SubjectID=t1.SubjectID 
                    AND t2.ID<=t1.ID
    )
GROUP BY ID, protocolID, SubjectID, imgDate1
```

...producing...

```
ID  protocolID  SubjectID  imgDate1    ColName
--  ----------  ---------  ----------  -------
 1  0388813     0001       2011-01-01  Date01 
 2  0388813     0001       1995-06-30  Date02 
 3  0388813     0001       2012-03-11  Date03 
 4  0388813     0001       2000-01-01  Date04 
 5  0388813     0002       2013-05-06  Date01 
 6  0388814     0001       2013-04-14  Date01
```

If we save that query as [tbl_event_xtab_base] then we can use it in a Crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Max(tbl_event_xtab_base.[imgDate1]) AS MaxOfimgDate1
SELECT tbl_event_xtab_base.[protocolID], tbl_event_xtab_base.[SubjectID]
FROM tbl_event_xtab_base
GROUP BY tbl_event_xtab_base.[protocolID], tbl_event_xtab_base.[SubjectID]
PIVOT tbl_event_xtab_base.[ColName];
```

...producing...

```
protocolID  SubjectID  Date01      Date02      Date03      Date04    
----------  ---------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0388813     0001       2011-01-01  1995-06-30  2012-03-11  2000-01-01
0388813     0002       2013-05-06                                    
0388814     0001       2013-04-14
```